# Bluetooth : Transferring call from Source to sink?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, a2dp

I have one android phone (Samsung S Duos)  that will act as SOURCE and one Audio Development Kit i.e. CSR 8670 which will Act as SINK. I am trying to activate the a2dp profile and than transferring the incoming call of my phone (Samsung S Duos) to the Kit(CSR 8670) but not able to achieve it. Please assist me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A2DP uses ACL packets, voice calls (handsfree) uses SCO packets over the air. 
The "Call" audio runs over SCO channel, so it is "technically" not possible to route calls to A2DP sink (unless you do some great hacks, which does not conform to the BT spec). Ideally you should use HFP for audio calls.

HCI can transport both ACL and SCO. BT chips often have PCM interface to which SCO data can be routed but usually its not accessible unless you can access the PINs of the chip.

Also, please try to ask some precise questions (with log/code) so that we can really assist you. If you ask some generic questions, it is difficult to answer.